# How to reference a linked service in an expression

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to reference a property of a linked service inside an expression.

How do I do something like:

```
@linkedservice("service_name").properties
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve doing this?

If you want to parameterize connections to data stores, try something like this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/parameterize-connections-to-your-data-stores-in-azure-data-factory/ This uses expressions inside the linked services.

Hope this helped!!

Comment: I need to pass in the url for the blob store to a custom activity - perferably I'd only like to have to define it in one place

Comment: Have you tried creating a dataset parameter and referencing a pipeline parameter? That way you only define the url in the pipeline, and the dataset will take the same value. Then add the parameter as a reference object in the custom activity.